# How to count duplicates in a hash in perl

Tags: perl

Please bear with me.

> Write a program that reads a series of words (with one word per line)<sup>1</sup> until end-of-input, then print a summary of how many times each word was seen. (Hint: remember that when an undefined value is used as if it were a number, Perl automatically converts it to 0. It may help to look back at the earlier exercise that kept a running total.) If the input words were fred, barney, fred, dino, wilma, fred (all on separate lines), the output should tell us that fred was seen 3 times. For extra credit, sort the summary words in ASCII order in the output.
>   [1] It has to be one word per line because we still haven't shown you how to extract individual words from a line of input.

This one should use a hash. And I can't figure out how. I can only think of using an array and using 2 loops to compare duplicates. I guess I didn't understand the problem right. Here's my code using an array.

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

chomp(my @input = <STDIN>);

foreach my $name (@input) {
    my $count;

    foreach my $compare_name (@input) {
        if ($name eq $compare_name) {
            $count += 1;
        }
    }

    print "$name seen $count times\n";
}
```

but this prints say for example:

```
myname
myname
myname

it prints:
myname seen 3 times
myname seen 3 times
myname seen 3 times
```

can somebody guide me on how to use a hash on this one? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to use a hash - what if you used the $name as the hash key?

Comment: yeah that's what i want but i dont know how to. Yes the $name as hashkey and then what to put in the hash value?

Comment: The word count, perhaps? :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is three times, because you have three iterations of the outer loop, each yielding same results (3 times).

A much simple way is:

```
my %occurs;
while (<STDIN>)  {
    chomp($_);
    $occurs{$_}++;
}

foreach my $occur (sort keys %occurs) {
    print "$occur seen $occurs{$occur} times\n";
}
```

Comment: yes, he's missed an `s` off `occurs`.  But you really ought to have been able to figure that out from the error message.

Comment: Fixed. (Also removed useless `= ()`.)

Comment: Not sure that straight out doing his homework (including the bonus points section) with barely an explanation is really the way to go.

Comment: @user2334809 You've accepted the wrong answer.  Ikegami's answer contains everything you need, without spoon feeding you code that you clearly don't understand.  Just copying this would be considered "cheating at your coursework", and frankly if you can't even figure this code out you've no chance with the rest of the course.

Comment: Studying by example is also a way to learn. But it's you're call, Ikegami's answer is much more detailed indeed. Also, nobody really explained the guy what he did wrong.

Comment: @Mattan I would agree, if I thought there was any chance that the OP is actually going to "study" your example rather than just copy it.

Comment: Don't underestimate him :) If I would try to solve a problem for some decent time, and than would actually see the "right" solution, I would sure try to understand.

Comment: Lol. Of course i understand his code. if you want i can explain it line by line. haha

Comment: @user2334809 sure, but you can only do that because of ikegami's answer!

Comment: Yeah one more thing i diddnt understand the undefined part too. so if somebody kind enough to enlighten it for me i would appreciate. lol

Comment: When you assign the first time `$occurs{$word}++` , no value is defined for `$occur{$word}`. In a number context , undefined is treated to 0, so actually the first time  `$occurs{$word}++` indeed can be treated as: `$occurs{$word}++` := `$occurs{$word} = $occurs{$word} + 1;` := `$occurs{$word} = undefined + 1;` := `$occurs{$word} = 0 + 1 =1 `

Comment: and so how is it a problem when $occurs{$_} will get 1 the first time? i still dont get it sorry.

Comment: @user2334809 it's not a problem, it should be _by design_ that this happens.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find out how many times you've seen a word, which is to say you're trying to access the count associated with a word.

If only you could use the word as the index into an array and store the count in that array element...

Well, that's exactly what a hash is. It's no surprise it was recommended by the exercise.

```
$counts{$word}     # Retrieves the count associated with a word.

++$counts{$word};  # Increment the number of times you've seen a word.

keys(%counts)      # Returns a list of the words you have encountered.
```

Comment: Thanks for this guide sir, im gonna use this to rebuild my code using hashing

Comment: but how do i save the inputted data from the user to a hash table? it only input 1 data so basically all datas inputted are all keys and no values. Is it right?

Comment: "Saving data"? You want to store counts. Specifically, you want to save a count one higher than the existing count. There's a convenient operator that does that: `++`.

Comment: @user2334809 heck, your notes even told you that you can add one to an undefined value and get one out.

Comment: @Alnitak, Adding one is bad advice as it gives a warning when adding to undef. `++` doesn't warn, which is why it's perfect here.

Comment: of course, I mean how else would you add one to a variable?! ;-)

Comment: @ikegami uhmmm. yeah i quite dont understand that part there where its stated the undefined thingy. Can you please explain an instance where there is an undefined value? i enter everything from keyboard. so how come there will be undefined?

Comment: @user2334809 I thought you said you understood that line of code?

Comment: yes the code of Mattan which IMO doesnt invlove the undefined thingy.

Comment: Consider this: What are you adding to when you first find a word? (Yes, his code involves undefined values. No, it doesn't give a warnings for reasons I've already stated.)

Comment: based on what i understand this is the line that saves the inputted word in the hash $occurs{$_}++; so in your question, i am adding the first found word to the hash, is it right?

Comment: You're adding 1 to `$occurs{$_}`, which is undefined (by virtue of not even existing) until that point. Incrementing by adding one (`$occurs{$_} = $occurs{$_} + 1`) would warn.

Comment: now now now, where did that 1 come? isnt it the $_ added to $occurs (a hash) and then increment with the ++ to add more based on the keyboard input?

Comment: ohhh.. based on your answer it adds 1 first am i right? because its pre-increment right?

Comment: @user2334809 it doesn't matter whether it's pre-increment or post-increment.

Comment: yeah i figure that out why it adds 1 the first time. But i still dont get it how is it a problem? it doesnt even give warnings or errors

Comment: `++$x` and `$x++` are both like `$x = $x + 1;` (but without the warning). The difference is in what they return when used in an expression.

Comment: What problem are you talking about? (Re "But i still dont get it how is it a problem?")

Comment: The only problem I see mentioned in the replies to this answer is that adding one (`$occurs{$_} + 1`) warns. Incrementing (`++$occurs{$_}`) was specifically lauded for not having this problem.

Comment: alnitak said that it's not a problem, its how it should be he said. Im just being curious why the problem brought that up (the undefined thingy) when you have nothing to do about it.

Comment: @user2334809 **there is no problem**  ikegami was just reminding me that `$foo = $foo + 1` will produce a warning if `$foo` is initially undefined, but `++$foo` (or `$foo++`) will not.  In all three cases `$foo` will end up containing `1`.

Answer (score -2):

Here is one way to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


use v5.14;
use strict;

my %map;
chomp(my @words = <STDIN>);

foreach my $word (@words) {
    $map{$word} += 1;
}

foreach my $key (sort keys %map) {
    say "$key occurs $map{$key} times."
}
```

It's simple, readable and easy to maintain.

Comment: What's with everyone doing this person's homework without a word of explanation!?